# Best approach for moving WPF NHibernate Client Server Desktop App to one that can be accessed from multiple places

Tags: wpf, nhibernate, desktop

Starting from scratch in terms of knowledge I have written a desktop application using WPF and NHibernate. This has helped me get up to speed with both NHibernate and WPF.

However, there is a requirement to make the application so that it can be accessed from mutliple places - these include handheld devices which have very simple web browser (no javascript capability), web services, Internet, the desktop application and potentially other user interfaces.

I believe this requires moving the application from its current NHibernate.dll deployed on the client to a web based application. The sheer choice of technology stacks is overwhelming and I am hoping I can get pointed in the right direction.

In essence, I want to be able to access the data from the server side in the desktop client, from the web service, from the handheld devices.

On the server side I guess I would have a web server(IIS?), NHibernate and a database and some way of communicating between the clients and the server.

What would be the best choice in this circumstance? Is it REST? SOAP? WCF? Something I don't know about / haven't mentioned?

Any assistance and advice from people who have implemented similar things would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you have already made most of the work on the desktop, moving the actual data access part on a webservice is not going to be hard.

If i were you i would make that transition and make a SOAP/WCF service have the same signatures (or at least as close as possible) as the data layer. This will make the transition for your already written desktop application easier. You will have to add code for synchronizing or just safety code for when the service is inaccesible.

For mobile access via a thin web client as the browser is, you are looking at a web site/application that touches the DB (possibly via the same data-access webservice) and generates html...

I can't advise between rest/soap/wcf as i have minor prior experience with all, but i can tell you that i have created a similar setup with a SOAP WebService feeding a Web Application and .NET Compact Framework Application for WM6+ and it works well.